# PC enters a 'sleep' mode after inactivity, won't turn back on

Tags: suspend, power-management

After maybe 30 minutes of inactivity, my pc stops all running programs and the screen goes black. The power light starts flashing and no input from the mouse, keyboard, or case buttons does anything. The only way to restart is to turn off/on my power supply.

I have tried running the following commands, and disabling power savings and suspend via the settings, but the problem still happens.

```
xset -dpms
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

It is running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

2x RX 580 4gb GPUs, MSI 970 Gaming Motherboard, Corsair RM 1000W Gold, AMD FX-8350 CPU, 8gb Kingston HyperX RAM (2x4gb), Western Digital 250gb Hard Drive

update:
The problem still exists on other operating systems - both linux mint and windows. I'm guessing its a hardware issue but not sure what

Comment: The flashing power light implies sleep mode but as comment under my deleted states this isn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved the issue if anyone has a similar problem. There was some sort of liquid that appeared to be leaking from my motherboard. It appears to be a known issue with the model.

I cleaned up parts of the board using rubbing alcohol and everything appears to be working fine. No more random shutdowns and no more POST beep codes.